# Can't set worksheet name as subaddress in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

Here's my code:

```
    Dim wsVar As Worksheet
For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
   With wsVar
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("G1"), _
 Address:="", _
 SubAddress:=Sheets("Table of Contents").Name & "!A1", _
 TextToDisplay:="Table of Contents"
   End With
Next wsVar
```

There's other code above it but that's all irrelevant to my issue. See the subaddress line?
I have tried essentially everything to get that subaddress to refer to a worksheet named Table of Contents in this same workbook. It won't work (I also don't know why I need the "!A1", but it seems I do from where else I've looked so it's there). 
When it does work, it creates a hyperlink, sure, but if you click that hyperlink it says the reference isn't valid. So I know it's this line of the code.

Answer (score 4):

When a sheet name includes spaces (and a couple of other special characters) you need to enclose it in single quotation marks, i.e. `SubAddress:="'Table of Contents'!A1"`.

(Or `SubAddress:="'" & Sheets("Table of Contents").Name & "'!A1"`, but it's a bit redundant to use the `.Name` property of a `Sheet` object to obtain the name you used as the index of the `Sheets` collection.)